# Phase Noise for OFDM systems (discrete-time Wiener process)

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, digital-communications, ofdm

I am trying to make a Matlab code for a phase noise model for OFDM systems, the literature suggests that the phase noise is modelled as a discrete-time Wiener process.
Could you please help me to build matlab code for phase noise model.

I found this code, it works fine but I don't understand it, please help me to understand it.

```
function phsnsig=add_phase_noise(xmtifft,freqspace,perctB)

perctB;
[str stn]=size(xmtifft);
T =str*stn;
B=freqspace*perctB;
randn('state',100) ;
dW = zeros(1,stn*str);
W = zeros(1,stn*str);
dW(1) = normrnd(0,sqrt(2*B));
W(1) = dW(1);

for j = 2:(stn*str)
   dW(j) = normrnd(0,sqrt(2*B*j));
   W(j) = (W(j-1) + dW(j));
end

xmtifft=xmtifft.';
xmtifft=xmtifft(:).';
xmtifftpn=xmtifft.*exp(i*(2*pi*4*10^(-6)).*W);
xmtifftpn=reshape(xmtifftpn,stn,str).';
phsnsig=xmtifftpn;

% phase noise plot
figure(14)
plot([0:T],[0,W],'r-')
xlabel('t')
ylabel('PN(t)')
title('Phase Noise for all Time Domain Samples')

end
```

Comment: I've used this for simulating phase noise and works great: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8844-phase-noise

Comment: I am struggling in modelling wiener process, I posted this question because I did not get reasonable results

Comment: No, I did not get reasonable results with it